# I Can't connect and parent specific bone points

Tags: rigging, bones

I want to connect and parent point 1 and point 2 together.

I have tried parenting and connecting them. The result is either:

- Nothing happens
- Point 1 connects to point 4
- Point 2 connects to point 3

Using Blender 2.92.

[image]

Comment: You can connect head to tail but not head to head or tail to tail

Comment: Oh so that is how they are called. Yes now that I know what to search for you seem to be correct... I will find some other way to achieve what I want then.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ3o5tjO51s from around 2:40.

Comment: @JohnEason That whole video is actually quite informative. Thanks for the help

Comment: In your example, 1 and 2 are called `root` in the blender documents but `head` in the actual interface.  3 and 4 are called `tip` in the blender documents but `tail` in the actual interface.  I think it's more common to use head and tail as the names, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blender Manual refers to points 1 and 2 as `root` and calls points 3 and 4 as `tip`  but almost everything else, including the user interface call 1 and 2 `head` and call 3 and 4 `tail`.

You can only connect bone heads to bone tails and if you parent one bone to another, then, as you've found out, if you use

- *connect* - it moves the child bone to connect its head to the parent bone's tail
- *Keep offset* - it doesn't move the bone, but the line showing the relationship will still be between the tail of the parent and the head of the child bone.  Here you can see the line.  The selected, yellow outlined bone, is the child in this picture.

  [image: child selected]

Comment: Head and Tail are used in the bone properties in Blender itself (Edit > N panel > Item) so I reckon that's what they should be called! :^)

Comment: To be honest, I think the only place I've ever seen root and tip is in the manual.